# How to take words from a list and use them as input and not allow words that are not on the list.[python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text, cmd

I wrote a simple code here:

```
c = ['USA', 'Iran']

def menu():
    print("Enter Command")
    choice = input()

    if choice == "c":
        print("**********")

        if choice == "USA"
        print("********")
```

It does not seem to work and i can kind of tell why.
but i don't know where to go from here :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand this at all. Can you show some examples of what the user might type, and what should happen as a result?

Comment: Don't put random tags on your question, this has nothing to do with the [tag:cmd] tag!

Answer (score 1):

Please correct the body of your if statements. You have made you second “if” statement a nested statement which I don’t believe was your intention.  If choice is USA should be right below the “if” from the first statement. And see if you can make use of “elif” rather than repetitive “if”. And don’t forget colons!

Answer (score 1):

You made a couple of errors but I believe the following is what you are trying to do. Try running the code and let me know if it's not

```
c = ['USA', 'Iran']

def menu():
    choice = input("Enter Command\n")

    if choice in c:
        print("**********")
        if choice == "USA":
            print("********")

menu()
```

You have to assign the "choice" variable to the input() function which returns whatever the user types in. The "\n" just helps with the formatting by bringing the cursor to the next line. The line "if choice in c:" checks if the choice variable is either USA or Iran. I also corrected the indentation for the nested if statement like what the other users have suggested. Lastly, you have to call the function using menu() for your program to run

Answer (score 0):

What does not seem to work? From the code in the question, it's apparent there are two syntax errors that should be detected by Python: missing ":" after if, and missing indentation after if (the second if).

Also, the code is not doing what you seem to mean in the question.

Maybe you mean this?

```
c = ["USA", "Iran"]

def menu():
    print("Enter Command")

    while True:
        choice = input()
        if choice in c:
            break
        print("Invalid input. Retry.")

    print("ok: " + choice)

menu()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for. I didnt know how to read from the list and use it as input. Thanks again :)